# How to update my local repo with overwiting the changes i've done

Tags: git, pull

i have pulled a gitlab repo, i've made some change on the code. But i saw that someone pushed something on the remote repo.
I'm wondering if i make a new pull request it will overwrite my changes ? 
Please help

Comment: If someone's new commits exists in remote `master`, Pull `master` into your local branch then create Pull request.

Comment: the pull request will will overwrite my local changes, right ?

Comment: Pull the changes if Conflicts happen then resolve it manually and keep your local changes.

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence "i have pulled a gitlab repo" , do you mean to say that you have done a 'checkout' of a repository?

Assuming that you meant that you have done a checkout, made some code changes, you need not worry. You can simply run the command "git merge master" to update your local repository with the changes in the remote repository.

In case of merge conflicts, git will prompt you with the next steps to merge the code.

Check this link: https://githowto.com/resolving_conflicts